# Definable sets, substructures and unions

Tags: model-theory

Ok so my question is as follows;
Let A be a substructure of B and S $\subset$ B be a definable set define by a universal formula $\phi(x)$, I need to show that in A $\phi$ defines $A \cap S$ My thought process was as follows, firsly we can define S as $S=\{ b \in B: B \models \phi(b) \}$ if i can show this is a substructure of B and show that $A \cap S$ is a substructure of B (which i think would be easy once i know S is a substructure of B, i can easily deduce what i am trying to prove using the fact (an exercise i just proved) that if a universal formula models B it models all substructures of B.

Any help or hints?

Comment: It doesn't seem true. For example, $\forall y(x=y)$ defines empty set in any nonsingleton structure, but not empty in a singleton. What is true, and is easy to check, is that $\varphi(B)\cap A\subseteq \varphi(A)$ (for universal $\varphi$).

Comment: Your claim is true if you add the following assumption: there is an existential formula $\psi(x)$ that is equivalent to $\varphi(x)$ both in $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Don't you want $A$ to be an **elementary** substructure of $B$ ? In that case, it directly follows from the definition of elementary embeddings.